# Mail Composer won't dismiss iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have ViewController with button, and action on button:

```
        - (IBAction)clickMe:(id)sender {
            MailHelper *helper = [[MailHelper alloc] init];
            [helper setAllData:self];
        }
```

Also, there is helper class for mail composing (MailHelper.h):

```
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>

    @interface MailHelper : UIViewController<MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>

    @property MFMailComposeViewController* mailView;
    - (void)setAllData:(UIViewController *)ctrl;

    @end
```

and implementation (MailHelper.m):

```
- (void)setAllData:(UIViewController *)ctrl {

    mailView = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mailView.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    mailView.toRecipients = @[@"mail@email.com"];
    [mailView setSubject:@"Subject"];

    [ctrl presentViewController:mailView animated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error {

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I can open mail composer, but while sending mail, saving draft or deleting draft app crashes. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok guys. Solution is to make instance of helper somewhere else, let's say:

```
@implementation ViewController
MailHelper *helper;
```

and:

```
- (IBAction)clickMe:(id)sender {
    helper = [[MailHelper alloc] init];
    [helper setAllData:self];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When the `MFMailComposeViewController` is request to be dismissed you are calling the dismiss method on `self` but `self` is presenting te `MFMailComposeViewController`.
Change:

```
-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error {

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

to

```
-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error {

    [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

To fix the deallocation issue add the following:

import the `<objc/runtime.h>` in you .m file and make `self` be associated with the controller passed:

```
static void * MailHelperKey = &MailHelperKey;

- (void)setAllData:(UIViewController *)ctrl {
mailView = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mailView.mailComposeDelegate = self;

objc_setAssociatedObject(mailView, MailHelperKey, self, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
....
}


-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error {

    [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    objc_removeAssociatedObjects(controller);
}
```

This will make sure that as long a the presenting control is not deallocated your mail helper. Does not deserve on price fro beauty but should work.

Comment: This is the solution for the posted issue. you must have another problem.

Comment: True. Thank you @rckoenes. Check out method clickMe:(id)sender. That method makes instance of MailHelper, but it shouldn't because when method is finished, memory is erased, so helper doesn't exist. Thats why you can't go back when draft is saved, or mail is sent... I hope you understand what am I talking about...